# Could not open jupyter notebook in Anaconda Terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I can open the jupyter notebook in the classical command prompt but when I try to open it in Anaconda(for python) it just doesn't let me. I tried to uninstall and install again but is not working. Can someone please help we with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you're not supposed to run the command `jupyter notebook` in python!

running the command directly without activating python should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like you are in a python shell. Try opening an Anaconda prompt. You should see the following:

```
(base) C:\Users\{YourUsername}>
```

Now, type

```
(base) C:\Users\{YourUsername}> jupyter notebook
```

and everything should work fine. Your state looks as if you typed

```
(base) C:\Users\{YourUsername}> python
```

which results in a prompt looking like

```
>>>
```

To fix this, run

```
>>> exit()
```

and then

```
(base) C:\Users\{YourUsername}> jupyter notebook
```